# What is the most effective exercise for the lower abs that one can do at home without any tools?

Tags: abdominals

Which single exercise can you recommend the most to train the lower abs at home without any required tools?

Comment: Could give "hanging pikes" a go. All you need is something to hang from.

Comment: Thanks @son15! Very appreciated. Unfortunately I have nothing to hang from. Do you have a suggestion for an exercise that works solely on the ground?

Comment: Upper and lower abs is a misnomer. There is just one sheet of muscle.

Comment: @JohnP my lower abs are less visible than the upper ones. Essentially I am looking for an exercise to make the lower ones more visible.

Comment: You may not actually have "lower abs" to make more visible. The divisions (4 pack, 6 pack, 8, etc) are genetic. If your lower area is not that visible, you may not have the fascia to create them, or it's also possible that you just carry more fat there and need to lose that to get the muscle striations visible. Pretty much any exercise that curls your front torso towards your lower body or curls your lower body up towards your torso will work the entire ab muscle top to bottom.

Comment: I second JohnP here, and would like to add that the diet is the second reason to genetics why the abs might not be visisble. Training is just about 20 % of the solution.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I very much appreciate them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can do [dead bugs](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=dead%20bugs) or similar exercises. A tip while doing these is to ensure your lower back is pressed into the floor at all times, don't let it arch (otherwise the hip flexor takes over the movement instead of the lower abs).

I like the following (called a leg drop or something):

1. Lie down and then raise your legs towards the ceiling. Tighten abs.
2. Slowly lower your legs until they’re a few inches above the floor (or as low as you can go without lifting the small of your back).

Repeat. Try to get a breathing pattern down (exhale when lowering legs works well). Do these until you feel the burn, count the reps and monitor how many you do as you progress.

(note, if lowering both legs is too hard you can lower one at a time, or you can bend at the knee. There are lots of ways to make it easier)

Comment: Your dead bugs exercise only works the abdominis in stabilization for the pelvis. The leg action is all through leg muscles. The abdominis flexes the lumbar vertebrae as a primary function. Since there is no spinal flexion, the only action the abs are serving is as stabilizers.

Comment: How fascinating.